# Is this an incomplete sentence? (from The Great Gatsby)

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

> Over the great bridge, with the sunlight through the girders making a
>   constant flicker upon the moving cars, with the city rising up across
>   the river in white heaps and sugar lumps all built with a wish out of
>   non-olfactory money.
>   -- from *The Great Gatsby* by F. Scott Fitzgerald

1) Is this an incomplete sentence?
2) Does the author write it like this to make it more poetic and lyrical?
3) Does "over" in "over the great bridge" mean above the bridge?

Answer (score 0):

This sentence definitely looks like an incomplete sentence, the way it is written.

I will split the sentence to help the analysis:

> - Over the great bridge,
> - with the sunlight through the girders
> - **making** a constant flicker upon the **moving** cars,
> - with the city **rising** up across the river in white heaps and sugar lumps
> - all **built** with a wish out of non-olfactory money.

Since all verbs (highlighted with **bold**) are participles / gerunds, we definitely do not have a predicate - therefore, the sentence is incomplete.

---

I just understood one detail - you may want to check.

It is possible that the author split a huge sentence artificially into several very long sentences. As a result, this sentence should be read together with the previous one(s) to make a full statement.

Similar example (mush shorter, though):

> It was dark. And rainy. And wind blowing. All over the city.

If you do not read "**It was dark**", the rest may not make much sense - as the only verb is "**was**".

The surrounding text is:

> Over the great bridge [...] **the city** seen from the Queensboro Bridge **is always the city** seen for the first time, in its first wild promise of all the mystery and the beauty in the world.

(taken from [here](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/f/fitzgerald/f_scott/gatsby/chapter4.html))

---

"Over" can have two meanings:
- above / on top of;
- on the other side.

Since we do not have the basic meaning of the sentence, we cannot guess the meaning of the details.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is a complete sentence. "Over the great bridge" is actually the subject. It means the area or land across, or on the other side of the bridge, or the view of said area. This is evident from the next sentence in the book:

> The city seen from the Queensboro Bridge is always the city seen for the first time, in its first wild promise of all the mystery and the beauty in the world.

The writer is describing his view of the city seen from the bridge, or from the other side of the bridge. It is not uncommon in English to substitute the name of a place for its location. For example, Australia is often referred to as "down under".

As for a *predicate* - sometimes sentences omit fragments if they are *implied*, and this is a form of creative writing as you suggest in your question. It is evident from the context that the narrator is describing what they can *see*, so it is as if they are saying:

> *I looked at the view* over the great bridge...

There are plenty of predicates in the sentence such as "*making a constant flicker upon*" and these act upon elemnts of the overall view that the narrator sees.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still confused. If "over the great bridge" is the subject so what is the predicate. I think the sentence can reduce to something like "Over the bridge all built with a wish from non-olfactory money." In that case, there's something may not right about the word "built". I think "built" is a past participle which modified "white heaps and sugar lumps" means those white heaps and sugar lumps are built from non-olfactory money.

Comment: @samrai I've added some detail.

Comment: There is no implied predicate. The predicate is in the next sentence, which was not provided by OP.

Answer (score -2):

As written, it is a fragment, not a sentence. It appears to be an adverbial phrase all on its own, albeit a rather long and ornate one.

However, we sometimes used fragments. Sometimes it's stylistic, breaking up a sentence so the predicate - the principal verb - is in one sentence, and additional adjectival phrases, subjects, adverbials etc are in apparently separate sentences. Sometimes it's because it's the answer to a question, and restating the question in an answer is unnecessary.

Sometimes it's because the verb, and even the subject, is simply understood. Specifically, in relation to this case, a group of people might pause on a journey and have a conversation, just before crossing a road. They might be waiting for a lull in traffic, or for a light to change. On noticing that it's now suitable to cross, one might interrupt and say:

> "Right then, over the road!"

I suspect Americans might say not say that, as they call it a *street* and don't have, nowadays, that idiomatic use of *over*. However, there is implicit verb and subject in that idiom in British English, to wit:

> **Let us cross** over the road

Reading that text *in situ*, I understand it as being essentially (but not precisely) the same. The narrator is saying that the character (or is it characters, I'm not sure which) is crossing the bridge. It makes the rest of the paragraph make sense, and fits with the wider context.

Creative writing is often creative with grammar and syntax as well. That doesn't make it wrong, but you shouldn't try and emulate it in any other sort of writing (except, possibly, rhetoric), and shouldn't try it until you feel very, very comfortable with the language.